# PPTXGENJS Is there a way to insert an HTML formatted text inside a slide?

Tags: pptxgenjs

Is it possible to insert HTML formatted texts inside a slide?

I need to insert a set of HTML formatted texts that was entered in a `WYSIWYG` input from `TinyMCE` in a powerpoint slide generated by PPTXGENJS.

If this is possible, I am looking for examples on how to do it. Articles or samples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try ? You are supposed to first try by yourself and come to SO for **specific** issue. See [ask]

Comment: Hello @xiawi, I only had tried [addText](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/api-text.html) to place the html text. It was placed on the pptx file as a plain text, also I can't find an option that will treat it as an HTML text.

Answer (score -1):

This solutions worked for me.

You need to create a table in html.

```
<table id="table-id">
</table>
```

Then you can append WYSIWYG (tinyMCE) content to this table.

```
$('#table-id').html('<tbody><tr><td>' + tinymce.activeEditor.getContent() + '</td></tr></tbody>');
```

Then use tableToSlides method.

```
pptx.tableToSlides('table-id');
```